# WCF Service in Windows Form Application

Tags: wcf, iis, self-hosting

I'm newbie in WCF. I have some questions need to be answered.

**Can I use WCF to make a simple chat application from a client to a client (via WCF Service)  ?**

I have tried follow many examples, And i got a problem. **I don't think that IIS need to be installed when i using WCF Selft Hosted, right ?**

Sorry about my English !

Comment: "Yes, but it would not be the best solution". And "Yes". If those answers are not helping you, maybe you could try to find a more constructive question.

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) Yes. Get to grips with just sending data one way first. Then do it the other way around. You ultimately need to understand the client/server configuration first, before writing chat mechanisms. The answer recommended by @Thorsten Dittmar would be the recommended approach, but it is an advanced scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IIS for self-hosted WCF services. Look at the [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Yes, you can make a chat application (client to client) using a service "in the middle". The clients would have to register with the service and then a [callback contract](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx) should do the job.

Comment: I follow this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/hosting-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding-in-windows-service/

And get stuck at step 8: An error appear when i hit Go button.

Cann't get metadata ...blah blah blah

Comment: This should go into another question, don't you think?